# Do I need to close an open NSFileHandle while concurrently reading the file in a different source?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilehandle

I'm logging data to a file that I keep open with NSFileHandle. These log files can be emailed out, is it necessary to close NSFileHandle before I send the email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to close the file handle but if you want everything that has been written so far, you should call `synchronizeFile` on the file handle to ensure anything in memory has been written to the file.

Comment: yes i'm doing a `synchronizeFile` but is there any documentation or reasoning you can point me as to why a concurrent write and read wouldn't cause a crash

Comment: How are you reading the file? There should be no problem copying the file even if another thread might write to the file. The OS will have no problem supporting that.

Comment: Using MFMailComposeViewController and doing `addAttachmentData:`, I imagine there is a read happening somewhere upon sending